# Why is the getchar() at the end necessary in this function? I don't see why it's there

Tags: c, getchar

```
void getInputData(void) {
    char c = 0;
    while (c != 'x') {
        printf("Enter a letter:");
        fflush(stdout);
        c = getchar();
        printf("You entered: %c \n",c);
        fflush(stdout);
        getchar();
    }
    printf("\nYou entered x and the loop exited\n");
}
```

Why is the `getchar()` at the end necessary in this function? I don't see why it's there.

Comment: Did you try what happens without the second getchar()?

Comment: It is to collect the `newline` still in the input buffer after `getchar`, but there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Maybe to read a newline since the first getchar() won't return unless ENTER is pressed?

Comment: And it'll be fun to watch that loop explode if somebody just hits the enter/return key, *without* typing a letter...

Comment: It also doesn't work too well if the user types `abcd` and then hits return (for any even number of visible characters).  The first time around the loop, the second `getchar()` gets the `b`.  The loop then prompts but 'reads' the `c` entered previously, and the second `getchar()` gets the `d`.  The loop then prompts again, reports that you entered a newline (you did), and the `getchar()` sits around waiting for more input (but there isn't a prompt to tell you). The second `getchar()` should probably be: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` to gobble characters to the newline.

Comment: @SteveSummit: hitting `^D` on unix or `^Z enter` on Windows sends it into a voiceful infinite loop too.

Comment: Why is there a `newline`  still in the input buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are using line-buffering in your program, *perfect* user inputs every time following letters until hits 'x':
T\n
H\n
I\n
S\n
x\n
Sending data works only when you press ENTER/RETURN key from keyboard. You should process `\n` newline character in order to get next character, that is why using `getchar()` is necessary.

Comment: `getchar()` is not *flushing buffer and making it empty*, it merely consumes the next byte, hopefully the pending `'\n'`.  Note that if the user types 2 characters before the enter key, the `getchar()` won't suffice.  The correct way is: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {}`

Comment: Why is there a `newline`  still in the input buffer?